I try to find a movie for a long time ago...I hope someone knowing its name
When i was a kid i watched a movie with my parents which scares me a lot back then. I really like to watch it now. 
I barely remember some of the scenes. One of them was how a women was in the bed and then the door opens and in the room came a man with an old lady mask. The second scene was how the same women was in the church and the same man came with the mask. As far as i remember this man had a twin and they both tried to scary the women.
I'd be really thankful if someone knows the movie and tells me the name. Thanks in advance! :)

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could this be Just Before Dawn (1981)?
